# Come up - English examples

Tags: word-usage

I have a few difficulties using the verb "To come up" or "To come up with". Could anyone be able to give me an explanation and some English examples of how to use this phrasal verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To come up** can mean  "to be mentioned, as a topic of discussion, or as a subject in conversation".

> Did the question of the mayor's business dealings with the mob *come up*
>   during the trial?
>
> When she was telling you about the dance, did his name *come up*?

**To come up with** can mean "to arrive at, as an idea":

> Which one of the mayor's lawyers *came up with* the brilliant idea that
>   the mayor had won the lottery, when asked to explain the large sum of
>   money in the mayor's  bank account?
>
> Juicing a lemon by placing it between two volumes of the OED is a pretty stupid idea. How did you *come up with* that?
>
> This pill lets you eat beans without becoming flatulent. I wonder who *came up with* the product jingle on the TV ad?

**to come up** can also mean "to rise through the ranks, as a student progressing through school, or a public servant or bureaucrat in an administration"

> He *came up* when Mr Jones was still headmaster of the school.
>
> When we *were coming up*, there was a midnight curfew for everyone under the age of 18.
>
> Smith *came up* through the ranks of the FBI during the Carter and
>   Reagan administrations.

**to come up** can also mean "to happen unexpectedly".

> I can't go to the game on Thursday as we had planned. Something has
>   *come up* that I must attend to.

Answer (score 0):

"To come up" can also mean gather, accumulate or acquire.

> I won't be able to come up with all that money by Friday.

It can also mean move in an upward direction.

> Come up to the apartment for a few minutes.